# Branching 2 folders in SVN?

Tags: svn, version-control

In my organization, SVN trunk is maintained as follow

1. trunk\Documents
2. trunk\Code
3. trunk\Design
4. trunk\ ..3 more folders.

I like to create branch for the Code & Design Folder(2 folders).  I am able to branch upto sub-folder, but not able to create branch for 2 or more folder.

I have two questions:

1. whether this option is supported in SVN?
2. If no, is there any work around to do this?
3. Or we need to change the repo structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as git implements branches as tags on a dag, svn implements branches as copies in a folder.  This being svn, make an empty-folder branch and `svn copy` what you want into it.

Comment: Can u please explain on how to merge with the trunk? I am getting 'http://...../DIRECT/trunk' shares no common ancestry with "C:\Localfolder"

Comment: [You create branches on the server not locally](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/), with `svn copy u://r/l/1 u://r/l/2`.  So make and commit an empty folder, svn copy that under /branches, then svn copy your folders there.  That should work.